# Exceptions in django stop the flow?

Tags: python, django

in my view I am executing this piece of code:

```
try:
    activeterm = LeaseTerm.objects.get(lease=lease, is_active = True)
except LeaseTenant.DoesNotExist:
    activeterm = None
```

And I expected there will be no value in `LeaseTerm`  I will get exception but I am getting an error:

> LeaseTerm matching query does not exist.

But I expected that I have handled the exception and flow should continue.

What is my miss understanding?

Comment: You should be catching `LeaseTerm.DoesNotExist`, not `LeaseTenant.DoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please retry with:

```
try:
    activeterm = LeaseTerm.objects.get(lease=lease, is_active = True)
except LeaseTerm.DoesNotExist: # LeaseTerm
    activeterm = None
```